# How to get percentage between current and previous rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I'm facing an issue and I need some help to resolve this issue.

My table contains this data:

```
Annee   NbExamen
-----------------
2017    2606    
2016    17833   
2015    14362   
2014    14673
```

and I want get these results:

```
Annee   NbExamen    % Change
-----------------------------
2017     2606   
2016    17833     ?
2015    14362     ?
2014    14673     ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select t.*, tnext.NbExamen as next_NbExamen,
       (tnext.NbExamen * 1.0 / t.NbExamen) - 1 as increase_rate
from t left join
     t tnext
     on t.annee = tnext.annee - 1;
```

Your question says "previous" but the sample data suggests "next".  Previous makes more sense:

```
select t.*, tprev.NbExamen as prev_NbExamen,
       (t.NbExamen * 1.0 / tprev.NbExamen) - 1 as increase_rate
from t left join
     t tprev
     on t.annee = tprev.annee + 1;
```